# UI Router query parameters not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I set UI Router up to have query parameters in the url, but when I did that it broke the search functionality on my app.

My states are like this:

```
  .state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
  controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
.state('search', {
  url: '/search?q',
  templateUrl: 'search/search.html',
  controller: 'SearchCtrl'
});
```

I have this code in both HomeCtrl and SearchCtrl:

```
$scope.searchTerms = $stateParams.searchTerms;
```

The HomeCtrl basically serves as an autocomplete/query page.

Then I have this:

```
$state.go('search', {q: $scope.searchTerms});
```

in my getSuggestions function on HomeCtrl and search function in SearchCtrl

In order for this to work, I have to search twice...? I enter the query and hit enter and the query appears in the url, then I have to hit enter again for the results to display. It doesn't work at all if I click the search button :(

If I comment out the `$state.go` line, search works but I loose the query parameters in the url and vice versa. It *seems* like `$scope` is getting `turned off` somehow?

Should I use `ui-sref` (it is more common) instead of `$state.go` for the linking? Am I suppose to put the `$state.go` code on the button element or something?

What am I doing wrong... so that search works and I have query parameters in the url?

Comment: I think you should change `$scope.searchTerms = $stateParams.searchTerms;` to `$scope.searchTerms = $stateParams.q;` since your state url has `?q` not `?searchTerms`

Comment: @plong0 I had already tried that, doesn't fix it

Comment: can you please show what `$scope.searchTerms` looks like?  do you receive errors in console?  maybe try `$state.go('search', {q: $scope.searchTerms}, {reload: true});`